# Access request setting change default permission from Edit to Read or View Only

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, requestaccessmail

I have read some answers on this site as well about how to have the default permission for Approve or decline email from Edit to Read or View only.

It seems that the way to do it is to set as default group the Visitors or the one with View Only permissions (let's take for example the Excel Service).

I have tried with both and when I approve from the email, it is still giving the user the Edit.

Has this changed for SharePoint online or it needs more time to understand that the visitors group is default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by designer that default permission for access requests is "Edit".

The user will be added to site members group. if you want to change default permission from Edit to Read or View Only,the only option is to change the site members group with Read or View Only permission.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/34398709-change-default-setting-for-access-requests-from-e